# JQuery .length returns 0. Doesn't return 0 in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to count the amount of elements in a Google Charts legend including the pagination element. Here's a basic markup:

```
<div id="piechart">
    <svg>
        <defs> </defs>
        <rect> </rect>
        <g>
            <rect> </rect>
            <g> ... </g>
            <g> ... </g>
            <g> ... </g>
            <path> </path>
            <g> ... </g>
            <path> </path>
        </g>
        <g> </g>
        <g> </g>
        <g> </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And here is what I'm trying to do in a $(document).ready():

```
var svg = $("#piechart svg");
var categoriescontainer = svg.find('g').first();
var countcategories = categoriescontainer.children('g').length;
alert(countcategories);
```

Countcategories always equals 0. However when I type in the same code in console after loading, I get 4. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you assume it to be 0. You may be misunderstanding it...

Comment: The SVG probably isn't quite ready when the DOM is. Tried doing the above inside a `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: j809: What? I don't "assume" it to be 0, it is 0.

Comment: Can you provide a (non-)working example? It's returning `4`, as expected, here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/flHur.

Comment: techfoobar: I didn't think of that, sounds likely, will try.

Comment: it workes well. http://jsfiddle.net/Junkie/fWvg8/

Comment: Is the HTML you show in the original document? Or is this what gets added by Google Charts? If it's added by Google Charts, then I suspect the problem is that your code is running before it's finished (or maybe even started).

Comment: @Cattla – it’s working as **jsFiddle** has set onLoad explicate and **codePen** runs code implicate after DOM ready

Comment: Yea, the issue was that Google Charts was getting added after onload/document(ready). Catching the callback fixed the issue.